# Return one-level result list from a join statement in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following simple join statement:

```
Dim result = (From PropertyDefinition In econtext.PropertyDefinitions
              Join ProductDef In econtext.ProductPropertyValues
                On PropertyDefinition.PropertyDefID Equals ProductDef.ProductPropDefID
              Where ProductDef.ProductID = 1
              Select ProductDef,
                     PropertyDefinition.PropertyDefName,
                     PropertyDefinition.PropertyDefName2,
                     PropertyDefinition.PropertyDefIIsDeleted).list()
```

If i explicitly included all columns under **ProductDef** it works, and the result comes in one list, currently the result of **ProductDef** is coming in a separated list:

[image]

I need everything from **ProductDef** and some from **PropertyDefinition** but not in nested lists,

How to get the result in one-shot list without the need to explicitly include all columns of **ProductDef**?

Comment: like this : `Select ProductDef.ProductPropValueID, ProductDef.ProductID, ProductDef.ProductPropDefID,etc`
instead of just `Select ProductDef`

Comment: @GertArnold,  The problem here is different, I don't have customization on the returned data , I only have two properties from the PropertyDefinition and 25 from the ProductDef, it is really painful to write it one by one in code.

Comment: I don't see any significant difference. What you want can't be done. There is no equivalent for SELECT * in LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

You're getting the `ProductDef` as a nested object because that's exactly what you're asking for when you specify `ProductDef` as one of the values to return: the `ProductDef` object itself, rather than any of its properties.

What you want seems to be the equivalent of SQL Server's `table1.*` syntax for requesting that all columns of a given table be returned, with the potential for returning additional values as well.  But I don't think that exists in LINQ.

It's possible you could work something up with dynamic data types that could do this, but honestly it'd be simpler just to list out all the properties you want.

ETA:  Or, you could create another type that had all the properties that you wanted, and create a constructor that took a `ProductDef` and a `PropertyDefinition` and populated all the fields from the constructor parameters.  That would deliver you an object that had all the properties you wanted.  But it would certainly be more work.

Comment: Exactly, I need it like the SQL Server return, The problem is, I only have two properties from the first and 25 from the second, it is really painful to write it one by one in code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to do with this anonymous type after creating it?  27 properties is a lot to display, so I assume you're doing something else with it.

Comment: A product management page, I wanted to collect all the required info in one query to be accessed after that from a grid on the client-side level, I did that to reduce the unnecessary database requests.